# Why can't I build Ruby code from Sublime Text 3 when I launch it from Ubuntu Dash vs Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: 16.04, ruby, sublime-text, ruby-on-rails

- `ruby -v`: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
- `which ruby`: /home/iuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby
- `rails -v`: Rails 4.2.3
- `subl -v`: Sublime Text Build 3126
- Ubuntu: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

It doesn't matter from which directory I launch the Sublime Text 3 from, as long as I launch it using `subl` from terminal, I am able to build any Ruby code, using the `Ctrl + B` even when the settings are the Tools > Build System > Automatic.

However, when I launch the same Sublime Text 3 from Ubuntu Dash, I am not able to build Ruby Code, and I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: ruby: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/iuser/Desktop/1.rb"]
[dir: /home/iuser/Desktop]
[path:/home/iuser/bin:/home/iuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Even though `$PATH` returns:

```
bash: /home/iuser/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/iuser/.rbenv/shims:/home/iuser/.rbenv/bin:/home/iuser/bin:/home/iuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
```

I was able to overcome this by making a custom build system which pointed to the rbenv and then changing the Sublime Text 3 Tools > Build System > MyCustomBuild (http://snakelab.cc/2014/12/10/sublime_3_and_rbenv.html)

My question is:

1. Why do I need to make a custom build system, and why its not picking up the rbenv just like the Sublime Text 3 which is started from terminal?
2. How can I make changes so that no matter where I start the Sublime Text 3 from, even if the build system is set to Automatic, it always builds the ruby code?

Comment: You probably have settings in `.bashrc` which add ruby to your PATH. If you add stuff to your PATH, use `.profile` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), I was able to fix this issue

Initially I did the configuration in the following manner:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

The correct method lies in echo-ing to ~/.profile instead of ~/.bashrc:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Just a small note, in order for this to work successfully, I had to restart. Logging out may have also worked as essentially your desktop session needs to resource ~/.profile